# TFS installation on Intranet?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

We are thinking about migrating to latest TFS version 2018.

We are planning it to install on intranet network, with secure SSL connection. My question is, would it require internet to work (Check-in, Build, Deployment etc.)? All our users are on same intranet network. Build & Database everything will be on same secured Intranet zone only connected to new TFS but without internet access.

So does it require internet access to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set up TFS  2018 in your intranet along with build servers etc. As long as your team members are on the same intranet, accessing TFS and using it for your projects, is possible. You can use builds deployments etc. as well within your intranet. However if you want to allow your TFS to deploy to machines outside of your network, let's say you have application that needs to be deployed to Azure app service, then you need internet connectivity to connect Azure subscription to your TFS. You may need to expose your TFS via internet, if you plan to do deployments to your clients environments, which are outside of your intranet, to get an agent setup in such environments to automate deployments.

Even though it is possible to use TFS 2018 only in the intranet without internet access, having internet access as well as exposing the TFS instance via internet provides with you additional benefits in deployments automation etc. Having said that it is possible to setup VPN connectivity with your client environments, to enable automated deployments, by allowing client environment agents to access your TFS. So it is possible as an option to use TFS without having internet access.

Comment: I think if user say "Build & Database everything will be on same secured Intranet zone only connected to new TFS but without internet access" so they do not need Azure. TFS works with [VMware](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.vmwareapp) and [System Center](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.scvmmapp). TFS with Release management can publish build results to any local resource.

Comment: Agree it is possible to use without internet. But I just wanted to highlight "IF" he ever needs to deploy to Azure, AWS as well. Just provided some additional information to make it clear that "IF" required pushing releases to clients environments outside of the local network.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Yes we do not have any plan to use Azure.

Comment: It brings quite a few benefits when you allow your TFS server to access the internet (like the described deployment scenarios, usage of extensions from the marketplace, integration of 3rd party services). But unless you have very specific requirements it is not necessary to expose the TFS from the outside of your intranet.